# Mac OS X echo $PATH gives strange directory. Xcode installed right?

Tags: python, c, xcode, macos, gcc

I am trying to figure out if Xcode was installed right because I am having trouble compiling a C program on my Mac OS X Mountain Lion. Why is the output of echo $PATH having anything to do with Python.framework?

```
Shanes-MacBook-Pro:all_dsc chimpsarehungry$ echo $PATH
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

I started researching this problem of having Xcode installed right because I get the following error when I try to compile a C program.

```
Shanes-MacBook-Pro:all_dsc chimpsarehungry$ gcc main.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_output_res", referenced from:
      _main in cc1YZOoj.o
  "_pred_acc", referenced from:
      _main in cc1YZOoj.o
  "_predict_sequence", referenced from:
      _main in cc1YZOoj.o
  "_read_sequence", referenced from:
      _main in cc1YZOoj.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I get a similar error when I type 'make'. I am brand new to this. I will post a question about running C programs and compiling in the future. But for now, I just want to address this weird directory I get.

Comment: The `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin` was added by Python and points to the path with the python binary. It has nothing to do with your XCode installation.

Comment: Ok sorry I'm really new to all of this.

Comment: The only way you can get this in your PATH is if you run the python.org (or other third-party) installer, and use the checkbox to let it modify your PATH. So you really shouldn't be surprised that it's there. If you don't want an extra Python on your PATH, just don't install an extra Python; the built-in one is fine.